# Plotting a csv file containing latitude and longitude into DEM (geotiff file)

Tags: python, gdal, matplotlib

I produced an elevation map. I want to plot my csv file named 'Coordinates.csv' that contains latitude and longitude points to my DEM (geotiff file) and the elevation map I produce will turn into latitude (y) and longitude (x) plot. When I import my DEM it is flip. I used gdal and matplotlib for plotting. How can I resolve this?
Here's my sample python code

```
from osgeo import gdal, gdalconst
import numpy as np
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import elevation
import affine
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

filename = "Sample-30m-DEM.tif"
gdal_data = gdal.Open(filename)
gdal_band = gdal_data.GetRasterBand(1)
nodatava1 = gdal_band.GetNoDataValue()

# convert to a numpy array
data_array = gdal_data.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float)
data_array


# replace missing values if necessary
if np.any(data_array == nodatava1):
    data_array[data_array == nodatava1] = np.nan


# Plot out data with Matplotlob's 'contour'
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.contour(data_array, cmap=plt.cm.terrain,
            levels = list(range(0, 2500, 100)))


ax.set(xlabel='Longitude (Degrees)', ylabel='Latitude (Degrees)', title='Sample Plot')
ax.xaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
ax.yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')

cbar = plt.colorbar()

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE! What do you mean with *it is flip*? If you mean that it is rotated 90° or 180° in some way, you can use the `np.flip()` function.

Comment: Matplotlib requires col, row ordering  while  GDAL reads in row, col  therefore  use numpy flipud as in [Plotting raster maps in python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/184767/2581)

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for answering. I just want to plot my csv file named "Coordinates.csv" into my DEM (geotiff). How can I do that? Thank you.